# initialising a 2D Binary Indexed Tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

this may be very trivial but i am not sure how to initialise a 2-d Binary Indexed tree. Generally we reset all the values to 0 . But how do we initialise the tree with the values of an array(say 1,2,3,4)? i am using the following update function but when i do

```
void update(int p, int v) // p  is the index, v is the value to be added
{
    for (int i=p; i<=MAXBIT; i+=i&-i)
    {
        bit[i][0] += v*(i-p+1);
        bit[i][1] += v; 
    }   
}
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
     update(i+1,array[i]);
```

i do not get the expected result..
Thanks.

Comment: after initialising  the tree with values(1,2,3,4) as in above method..when i do a query for a range(1,4) i get 20 instead of 10

Comment: What do you mean "query for a range(1,4)"? Can you provide a complete compilable example of the problem you're having?

Comment: This question is underspecified.